# WiX: lght0103 error for every file in directory

Tags: xml, wix, installation, windows-installer

I am tasked with making an msi for a piece of software. `heat` seems to run well, and it creates all of the necessary components. when I run `light`, however, it spits out

`error LGHT1013 : the system cannot find the file 'Users\****\Desktop\myApp\...`

for each file, unless i specify an absolute file path (incl. the drive letter, ex. C:\Users\....\foo). I am an absolute newbie to WiX, but from what I gather, my `SourceDir` is set to Users\****\Desktop\myApp. I cannot use visual studio tools like isWix as this is an eclipse project on a work computer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not have Eclipse and Visual Studio installed?  IsWiX works with Visual Studio Community Edition (free if you are smaller then an enterprise ) and Visual Studio Integrated Shell  (  Just the VS IDE without any of the programming languages ).

Otherwise if you tell me what you want the installer named I could use the IsWiX project templates to create you a solution.  You don't need Visual Studio to build WiX projects, just MSBuild (.NET Framework)  called from a .BAT file.  The merge module .wxs can be authored using IsWiX from the start menu and other files can be edited using Notepad or other favorite text editor.

IsWiX consumes files from a staging directory. It doesn't care what compiler was used to create them.